# DXA framework for Single Page apps with XPM support

Tags: dxa

Is there a DXA framework that is integrated with some JS framework (Angular, react or vue) and that support XPM? It would be good to create single page application if there is some framework like this. Please share.

I know that same question was asked in 2017, but I am asking again because there could be many more upgrades since 2017.

Answer (score 1):

There is no client-side, JavaScript-based DXA Framework for Tridion Sites yet (it is still on the SDL Tridion Sites roadmap, though).

However, there is such a framework/module for Tridion Docs: the
[DXA Dynamic Documentation Module](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-D36601FA-88DD-48A6-A8C0-61159673C2F4)

Comment: Like Rick mentioned, there is no community framework that is available for SDL Sites but  we can build one from scratch since content delivery is separated from content manager for SDL Sites. The product does support SPA and even headless implementations.

Comment: Thanks both for sharing the details.